# How do I get Firefox console to show more than 200 log entries?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console.log

Here is the code I want to print to console:

```
for(var j=0; j<300; j++){
    console.log(j);  
}
```

I want to display all `j` in console. But for some reason, only 100-299 gets printed out.

I am using Firefox built in Web Developer tools.

Comment: built in console or firebug?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In about:config you can up the limits

Firebug:

```
extensions.firebug.console.logLimit
```

Built in Web Developer tools console:

```
devtools.hud.loglimit.console
```

Comment: However if the console is closed when the script runs, you'll still see only the last 200 entries when you open it up..